# Random nilpotent and upper triangular matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Suppose a $4$ by $4$ matrix $A$ is nilpotent and upper triangular, and all $(i, j)$ entries for $i < j$ are chosen randomly and uniformly in the interval $[−1, 1]$. What are the probabilities that its Jordan canonical form corresponds to the partitions
> \begin{gather*}
>   4 = 4, \qquad
>   4 = 3 + 1, \qquad
>   4 = 2 + 2, \\
>   4 = 2 + 1 + 1, \qquad
>   4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1?
> \end{gather*}

I don't have any ideas about this question. Please give me any insights or ideas.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: With probability $1$, *all* elements of $A$ in the strictly upper triangular part are nonzero and hence the Jordan form of $A$ is a $4\times4$ nilpotent Jordan block.